# Selecting form input with Selenium isn't working?

Tags: python, selenium

I was making an software which should connect to website using Selenium (firefox, python) and click "Yes" button. Here's page's source code (just that form part):

```
<div class="grid_24">

            <div class="content_block">

        <form action="" method="POST" class="fatform">
            <p style="text-align:center;">
                <input style="margin-right:50px;float:none;" type="submit" name="yes" value="da">
                <input style="float:none;" type="submit" name="no" value="ne">
                <input type="hidden" name="checkthis" value="lpftvqenq">
            </p>
        </form>

    </div>
```

I was looking at [Selenium Python Docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html) but I couldn't solve it by myself. So I'm here. I tried few types of selecting elements like this:

```
proxy(ip, port).find_element_by_name('yes').click()
form = proxy(ip, port).find_elements_by_class_name("fatform") #printing this gives nothing
proxy(ip, port).find_element_by_css_selector(".yes[value='da']").click()
```

All these examples (except form string which returns "") return NoSuchElementException.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not search for the element by xpath instead?  From my experience, the XPath generated by the Firebug add-in for Firefox works extremely well for me.

```
proxy(ip, port).find_element_by_xpath("xpath text").click()
```

Comment: I got correct Xpath using Xpath Helper Chrome Extension but again, I get same error (NoSuchElementException). Xpath Helper gave me this Xpath:

proxy(ip, port).find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@class='container_24']/div[@class='grid_24']/div[@class='content_block'][1]/form[@class='fatform']/p/input[1]").click()

Comment: I haven't had any luck using the XPath that Chrome provides.  I am not quite sure why that is and haven't put forth any effort to understand why.  I only have Firefox and Firebug installed for XPath's as all testing is done IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong selector.

`.` in css selector means class which is not the case here. Should look like

```
[name='yes'][value='da']
```

**EDIT**
Including explicit wait

```
WebDriverWait(proxy(ip, port), 10).until(
            EC.find_element_by_css_selector((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='yes'][value='da']"))

proxy(ip, port).find_element_by_css_selector("[name='yes'][value='da']").click()
```

Comment: Still it's unable to find it: NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".fatform[name='yes'][value='da']"} and

NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name='yes'][value='da']"}

Comment: Is that element inside an iframe?

Comment: See my edit. Without knowing much about the page I can only tell this might be a element load issue and if so the `explicit` wait should be good enough for you